# Linq query results to List

Tags: vb.net, linq-to-sql

I have the following....

```
Dim ProjectToDelete As Project2Host = dc.Project2Hosts.Single(Function(p) p.Host = tb_Host.Text)
dc.Projects2Hosts.DeleteOnSubmit(ProjectToDelete)
dc.SubmitChanges
```

This worked fine as there was only ever one Project associated to a Host.

The rules have now changed and there can be more than one Project per Host. I now need to create a List of ProjectsToDelete and populate that with a Linq query and then do a DeleteAllOnSubmit(ProjectsToDelete).

How do I create the list? I've beem trying .SelectMany but with no joy.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
For Each item in dc.Project2Hosts.Where(Function(p) p.Host = tb_Host.Text)
    dc.Projects2Hosts.DeleteOnSubmit(item)
Next
dc.SubmitChanges()
```

OR:

```
dc.Project2Hosts.DeleteAllOnSubmit(dc.Project2Hosts.Where(Function(p) p.Host = tb_Host.Text))
dc.SubmitChanges()
```

Comment: Great... I used the second option but corrected it to dc.Project2Hosts.DeleteAllOnSubmit(.....) Thanks... I was getting all mixed up creating a List(Of Project2Host) and then trying to AddRange(myquery)... so simple when you know how. Thanks Ric

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to put that in. Updated. Did it work? You could have removed the contents within `DeleteOnSubmit()`, called `.ToList()` on it and placed that in there instead, but there's no need.

Comment: I have to get used to stop using return when adding comment. Was editing when you posted your last reply. All worked Thanks

Comment: No worries, if it was the answer feel free to mark it as so :)